# Add percentile lines to scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

[image]

I have created a scatterplot as shown in the image. I tried adding percentile lines which resulted in the three horizontal lines you see in the image. Those three lines look to be percentiling all the data.

Instead, I would like to percentile by group. So the 75th percentile line will start at the top of value 2 on the x-axis, it will join to the 75th percentile for the value 4 on the x-axis and so on.

Example of what i am trying to create is below:

[image]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
plot(LS10StDev$Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio, 
     LS10StDev$X10.Year.Standard.Deviation, 
     xlab ="Number of Managers in Portfolio",
     ylab = "10 Year Annualized Standard Deviation", 
     main = "Long/Short Managers - 10 Year Standard Deviation",
     pch = 20, col='dark green') 

abline(h=quantile(LS10StDev$X10.Year.Standard.Deviation,c(0.25,0.5,0.75)))
```

Comment: You'd need to calculate the percentiles and use `lines`, as `abline` only draws straight lines.

Comment: It would help if you provided the data that you are plotting. Probably the best way for you to do this would be `dput(LS10StDev)` and then pasting the result into your question.

Comment: Thanks alistaire
what is the syntax for Line? Should i calculate it with the raw data in excel and call it in RStudio or calculate it within R?

Answer (score 2):

I generated some bogus data to illustrate.

```
## Generate some data to approximate your picture
set.seed(42)
X10.Year.Standard.Deviation = c(rnorm(20,9.5,1), rnorm(20,8.2,0.8), 
    rnorm(15,8.4,0.6), rnorm(10, 8.2, 0.4), rnorm(2,8.0, 0.1))
Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio = rep(seq(2,10,2), c(20,20,15,10,2))
LS10StDev = data.frame(Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio,
    X10.Year.Standard.Deviation)

## Plot points
plot(LS10StDev, ylim=c(0,15), pch = 20, col='dark green')

## calculate quantiles and plot lines
Q25 = aggregate(LS10StDev$X10.Year.Standard.Deviation, 
        list(Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio), quantile, 0.25)
Q50 = aggregate(LS10StDev$X10.Year.Standard.Deviation, 
        list(Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio), quantile, 0.50)
Q75 = aggregate(LS10StDev$X10.Year.Standard.Deviation, 
        list(Number.of.Managers.in.Portfolio), quantile, 0.75)
lines(Q25, col="red")
lines(Q50, col="green")
lines(Q75, col="blue")
```

[image: Points and Lines]